# Mongodb: UpdateMany not update nested array data

Tags: mongodb

I try update many data but it doesn't updated. I'm using command like this

```
db.transactions.updateMany({"request_by.0.userId":"060dcaf49c13e9c380ebfccd"},{$set: {"request_by.0.city":"aaa"}});
```

result

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 2, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

my data of transactions collection

```
{
    "_id": "9e2dfeec3f31db6415108a3d",
    "request_by": [{
        "userId": "060dcaf49c13e9c380ebfccd",
        "email": "derp@gmail.com",
        "tel": "0128371827",
        "name": "Derp the joker",
        "role": "guest",
        "iat": 1545564382,
        "exp": 1545582382
    }],
    "status": "active",
    "invoice": "2018122318410976",
    "created_at": "2018-12-23T11:41:09.203Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-12-23T11:41:09.203Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: What mongo version? It is working as expected on 4.0.4.
How do you insert the original document?

Comment: im using mongo version 4.0.5